# Using plyr.io with youtube embedded gives "cannot read property of play of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, youtube, html5-video, plyr.js

I am dynamically loading embedded youtube videos into the http://plyr.io custom player

```
  player.source({
    type:       'video',
    title:      'Example title',
    sources: [{
        src:    '5WU7oGiwiao', // youtube 11 digit id
        type:   'youtube'
    }]
```

However I am receiving the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined.

This error is blocking other elements of my javascript from executing but I cannot figure out why it is happening.

The error doesn't occur if I load the player statically

```
<div class="plyr"><div data-type="youtube" data-video-id="5WU7oGiwiao"></div></div>
```

JSFiddle: http://codepen.io/cwaldau/pen/JbXjKW

Thank you